# I want to perform find operation on mongodb using scala drivers

Tags: scala

```
def find(query: Document, projection: Document, collectionName : MongoCollection[Document]) : Document = {
            var previousDoc : Document = Document()
/*var future = collectionName.find(query).projection(projection).toFuture()*/
                    try {
collectionName.find(query).projection(projection).subscribe(
                                (data: Document) => previousDoc = data,
                                (error: Throwable) => println("error"),
                                () => println("Completed")
                                )
                    } catch {
                    case x:Exception => throw new MongoCustomException(x)
                    }
    //Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
Thread.sleep(1000)
    previousDoc
    }
```

Here is my code snippet, If i did not use Await or Thread, I will get empty document. It is exiting before getting the data from mongodb. I want to run this process synchronously in Scala that is without using Await and Thread approach.

Comment: which mongo client you are using ?

Comment: You could call `toFuture` on the `Observable` that you obtain from the query and then pattern match on it to get the value.

Comment: You can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a var to obtain the value from observable. Your program stops before the Future is completed and the mutable variable hasn´t any value from Mongo. Transform the Observable to Future

```
val r = collectionName.find(query).projection(projection).toFuture
```

If you want this value before your program exits your Thread must wait with Await.result(r, 10 seconds). In your case, you have your code inside a function which is executed in one thread and the "previousDoc = data" does not block it, so it simply returns. Change the return type to **Future[Seq[Document]]**:

```
def find(query: Document, projection: Document, collectionName : MongoCollection[Document]) : Future[Seq[Document]] = {
 collectionName.find(query).projection(projection).toFuture()                    
}
```

Scala Mongo Driver works in an asynchronous way using Observables or Futures. So try to work in that way.